# Is there any maximum image size that should be there in RDLC reports?

Tags: reporting-services, report, rdlc, reportviewer, microsoft-reporting

Does the RDLC reports with images have any restriction for the image resolution sizes when displaying?

Comment: RDLC is a webpage.  So images are the same as with WEB and you have to consider the size, resolution, time to download, and time to paint.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error when exporting RDLC reports having large images into word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72392808/error-when-exporting-rdlc-reports-having-large-images-into-word)